# unzip all files and save all contents in a single folder - unix

Tags: unix

I have a single directory containing multiple zip files that contain .jpg files.

I need to unzip all files and save all contents (.jpgs files) into a single folder.

Any suggestions on a unix command that does that?

Please note that some of the contents (jpgs) might exist with same name in multiple zipped files, I need to keep all jpgs.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
unzip '*.zip' -o -B
```

as by default these utilities are not installed
see http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/how-can-i-zipping-and-unzipping-files-under-linux.html regarding installation

read about -B flag to realize its limitations.